# Webform CiviCRM and Gift Membership

Tags: civimember, webform-civicrm

Is it possible to use Webform CiviCRM Drupal module to create Stand Alone Forms for gifting a membership to a third party?

Comment: Do you mean in addition to a membership for themselves, or just a stand-alone form for a gift membership for a third-party?

Comment: Stand-alone gift membership for third party.

Seems like if I add two contacts to the webform, I can assign a membership to the second one, and then a contribution page can be linked on that tab with an "In Honor of" field. I wonder if that would work?

Comment: Sounds like a good direction but you may not need the "in honor of" field -- you can add a relationship between the two contacts if you like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with Webforms. Create two contacts on the webform. Contact 1 will pay (that's always the case with contact 1), you can set contact 2 to receive the membership. Incidentally you could also add contacts 3, 4, etc. to also receive gift memberships.

More details can be found [in these instructions](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Webform+CiviCRM+Integration).

Comment: That's brilliant!