# Does the Gift membership extension work with 4.7?

Tags: civimember, gift-memberships

Does anyone know if Civicrm's Gift Membership extension works with 4.7?

https://civicrm.org/extensions/gift-memberships shows stable releases up to 4.6.

Parenthetically, I'm also aware of Coleman's suggestion of using webforms to create gift memberships here: [Webform CiviCRM and Gift Membership](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6306/webform-civicrm-and-gift-membership). But the Gift Extension provides individual access codes which start the membership when the gift recipient chooses, which is a great feature.

Thanks for any thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fuzion have now updated this extension for us... we have details if anyone is interested. Thanks team.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in [git](https://github.com/relldoesphp/com.aghstrategies.giftmemberships/issues/8) here asking this very question but without any answers since Nov 2016 and last commit is nearly 2 years ago. Worth raising the question here since it has a broader audience

UPDATE

changes have been pushed to the main extension repository - https://github.com/relldoesphp/com.aghstrategies.giftmemberships/pull/11.

This will enable users to use the extension on 5.x versions

Comment: Have you been using this extension successfully with Civi 5.x?

Comment: yes with jitendra's fixes

Comment: evan see above update

Comment: Graçias, señor.