# Changes to Contributions that would break GiftMemberships Extension?

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, contribution-page, gift-memberships

We have tried deploying the com.aghstrategies.giftmemberships extension to a 5.x CiviCRM.

The form PostProcess hook where all the magic happens is not working because the _contributionID is empty (but it is present) in the $form argument passed to the hook implementation.

Has anyone successfully deployed this extension on 5.x?

Can someone familiar with the changes to Contributions since 4.6 explain what is wrong with the approach the extension is using and what would be necessary to fix it?

Hook Implementation:
https://github.com/relldoesphp/com.aghstrategies.giftmemberships/blob/master/giftmemberships.php#L88

retrieval of contribution ID that is always null:
https://github.com/relldoesphp/com.aghstrategies.giftmemberships/blob/master/giftmemberships.php#L136

Comment: NB that we have also tried installing from the repo with what we believe to be the changes that were necessary for the extension to work on Civi 4.7.

https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20565/does-the-gift-membership-extension-work-with-4-7

https://github.com/jitendrapurohit/com.aghstrategies.giftmemberships/commit/325aeaa7c48aa63938984eb6e04a0f4ac8152dea