# How can I create a D9 webform where contact 1 pays for a membership that applies to contact 2?

Tags: drupal, civimember, webform-civicrm, contributions, gift-memberships

I want to set up a Drupal 9 webform to enable people to buy a gift membership. I don't want to use the Gift Membership extension because it's approach of creating a redeemable code doesn't fit with our business processes: we want to be able to contact the recipient of the gift membership directly as part of the on-boarding process, and create a relationship between the purchaser and the holder of the membership.

So I need the webform to create the two contact records in CiviCRM so that I can then communicate appropriately to both the purchaser and the member.

My work so far on this seems to indicate that this isn't achievable, but I may well be missing a trick. Webform_CiviCRM appears to assume that any contribution is linked to Contact 1 in the form (there's no option to choose the contact that will be linked to the contribution record). If I then specify that I want a membership for Contact 2, the price for the membership doesn't appear to get included, so the total is always 0, and no payment can be processed.

Can I use the 'in honour of' element? (never used it before so I'm unclear as to what it actually does).

Has anyone got anything like this working? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: does this provide any hints? https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6306/webform-civicrm-and-gift-membership

Comment: Thanks - already seen that. It appears to relate to D7, and the link to instructions is broken as it's pointing to the old wiki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing. It feels a bit weird, but so far it seems to do the trick.

Having created the fields I need for the two contacts, and ensuring that buyer is contact 1 (because the contribution appears to only work for contact 1), I can then specify a membership that will be applied to contact 2.

Even though I've set a minimum price for the membership in CiviCRM, the form seems to take no notice of this. So in order to have a price appear on the form, in the Civi settings tab for the form I enable a contribution. This still doesn't let me set a price anywhere, so in the form component for Contribution Amount I set a default value - the price I want to set, and I configure the form component so that it is read-only (otherwise the user could edit the price).

The form now looks sensible, a payment gets processed for the right amount, and a membership gets created.

What I need to try to work out now if how I can provide a choice of price options?

Comment: Yes, this seems right, I'm not sure what parts are feeling weird. An important thing about webform civicrm is that it doesn't have the same kinds of built-in hard-coded "business rules" that the civicrm forms have. That's good and bad, but for flexibility and defining those rules yourself, it's definitely good. To answer your last question, I think you would convert the price field to a list box.